# Как получить объект из двух массивов?

Tags: javascript, массивы

В методе приходит два массива `array1(id1...idn) array 2(aelem1...elemn)`.

Как из них составить объект новый вида

```
Obj = {
  array1[I]: array2[j]
}
```

Например

```
Obj = {
   Id1: elem1,
   Id2: elem2,
   Id3: elem3,
   ...
}
```

Comment: Если Bам мой ответ подошел, то почему бы не поставить галочку :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var keys = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
var values = [11, 22, 33]

var result = {};
keys.forEach((key, i) => result[key] = values[i]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr1 = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
var arr2 = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
var obj = {};
for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
 obj[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Для разнообразия

```
function Fu_0001(_arr, _markerKey){
    if(_arr.length){
        this[(_markerKey || "") + _arr.length] = _arr.pop()
        this.constructor.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }
}

console.log(new Fu_0001(["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"],"Id"))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr1 = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
var arr2 = ["elem1", "elem2", "elem3"];
var obj = arr1.reduce(function(map, x, idx){ map[x] = arr2[idx]; return map; }, {});
```