# Не работает создание объекта с именем через переменную

Tags: javascript

Доброго дня суток всем, у меня не получается создать объект так чтобы имя его свойства было заданное через переменную, вообщем лучше смотреть код:

```
var collector = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i<mass.length; i++){
    var name = "obj"+i;
    collector[name] = new Object();
}
```

По плану должно в объекте должно появиться несколько объектов с именами "obj1", "obj2" ... но вместо этого появляется один объект с именем "name".

Я знаю что где-то туплю, но где именно понять не могу помогите пожалуйста.

Заранее спасибо.

Да и в догонку такое присвоение неплохо работает с числами, он правда создает объект в объекте или просто создает двумерный массив?

Comment: У меня ваш код работает как надо, ошибко тут тоже не вижу.

Comment: вот тема в которой обсуждали похожий вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/755204/Как-получить-объект-из-двух-массивов/755231

Answer (score 1):

Что-то Вы не договариваете. Ваш код отлично работает

```js
var collector = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var name = "obj" + i;
  collector[name] = new Object();
}
console.log(collector['obj2']);  // {}
console.log(collector['name']);  // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) { // from 1 to 10
    window["Object"+i] = new Object();
}
console.log(Object7); // is not undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

Не стоит путать

```
collector[name] = new Object();
collector.name  = new Object();
```

В первом случае получится то, что ты хочешь, а во втором - то нежелательное поведение, которое ты описываешь.

PS: Однако в данном вопросе ты привёл код, который работает верно.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код рабочий, можно проверить тут.

```js
var collector = new Object();
for (var i = 0; i<5; i++){
    var name = "obj"+i;
    collector[name] = new Object();
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(collector));
```

> он правда создает объект в объекте или просто создает двумерный
>   массив?

collector это объект,  дочерние элементы его collector.obj[1-N] это тоже объекты.